# Dynamic angularJS function call

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write a HTML tag

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in getusermenu">
<a ng-click="ctrl.{{key}}()" ng-href="#!{{key}}">{{value}}</a></li>
```

. Here I am getting values of `key` and `value` successfully. But the problem here is 
`ng-click="ctrl.{{key}}()"` is not calling the function. But when I am hardcoding(`ng-click="ctrl.functionName1()"`) the function name it's running fine. The problem here is, angular js is not printing the `key` if it is in middle. How I can achieve this?

Comment: I have tried ng-click="ctrl.[key]()"

Answer (score 2):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to access object property by variable name:

```
ng-click="ctrl[key]()"
```

Comment: Good thanks! I was just bracket notation, the problem with me was "dot" ctrl.[key]()